# select custom array element by index from document field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Ho can I select specific array element by index defined in document?

For example I have following document:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "idx" : 1, "vals" : [ 1, 2 ] }
```

And I want to select `vals` element defined by `idx` index.

I have managed to select specific array element defined by literal:

```
> db.test.find({_id:1}, {vals:{$slice:[1, 1]}})
{ "_id" : 1, "idx" : 1, "vals" : [ 2 ] }
```

But how can I use `idx` field in `$slice` operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optimal way to do this is in MongoDB 3.2 using the [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) operator:

```js
db.test.aggregate([  
    { "$project": { "vals": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$vals", "$idx" ] } } }
])
```

---

You can also use `findOne` if you use `_id` in your query criteria and to get `idx` value.

```js
var idx = db.test.findOne({ "_id": 1 }).idx
db.test.find({ "_id": 1 }, { "vals": { "$slice": [ idx, 1 ]}})
```

With `find` you need to use [`cursor.map`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.map/)

```js
db.test.find().map(function(doc) { 
    doc.vals = doc.vals.slice(doc.idx, 2); 
    return doc; 
})
```

Result:

```js
[ { "_id" : 1, "asd" : 1, "vals" : [ 2 ] } ]
```